# How to insert breakline in td

Tags: html, css

I go through with many articles but don't find exact solution that's why I come with question.

I have one `<td>` and inside this table cell there is 5 `<a>`

What the css code if I want to insert break line after each `<a>`

I used `white-space` , `float:left` , `content:{"\A"}` , `display:block` no option work with my scenario.

Please help.

Comment: Why not simply make them `width:100%` so they stretch and push other blocks out of the way? And `display: block` should have worked as blocks always try top get full width and will push things out of the way. Could you provide your code? _Minimally_? As in the HTML you used and the CSS you tried to apply to that? Then we can see what went wrong and where.

Answer (score 0):

`display: block` works:

```css
a {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<table>
<tr>
<td><a>asdasd</a><a>asdasd</a><a>asdasd</a><a>asdasd</a><a>asdasd</a><a>asdasd</a></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<tr>
</table>
```

Comment: The question says `display: block` is not an option in this case.

Answer (score 0):

If pure `a {display: block}` does not work for you, then try using:

```
a {
   display:block !important;
}
```

`!important` might not be the cleanest solution, but it should do the job.

But there must be a reason why clean `display: block` does not work for you. Could you please provide your code?